# Отображение экрана загрузки

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

В форме есть метод, который выполняет трудоёмкую задачу - загружает большое кол-во строк из базы данных. И есть загрузочный экран, который тоже является минимальной версией формы - простой splash screen, который выводит сообщение "Пожалуйста, подождите". Вот примерный код выполнения:

```
    private void foo()
    {
        LoadingSplash.DisplayLoadingWindow();
        LoadDatabaseData()));
        LoadingSplash.CloseLoadingWindow();
    }
```

Внутренности методов вывода загрузочного экрана:

```
    public static void DisplayLoadingWindow()
    {
        _loadingWindow = new LoadingWindow();
        _loadingWindow.Show();
    }

    public static void CloseLoadingWindow()
    {
        if (_loadingWindow != null) { _loadingWindow.Close(); }
    }
```

Логика отображения этого экрана следующая: сначала выполняется вывод на экран этого loading splash screen, потом начинается выполняться трудоёмкая задача, и по завершению - закрываться загрузочный экран. Но вот незадача - загрузочный экран не выводится. Почему? И как решить данную задачу?

Comment: Просто предположу, что вы грузите свои данные в UI потоке и потому у вас все прилодение встаёт колом.

Comment: По всей видимости, необходимо вынести трудоёмкую задачу в отдельный поток. Но возникает вопрос: каким образом отследить завершение выполнения этой задачи, и в UI потоке оповестить об этом Loading Window для закрытия?

Comment: Вопрос не полный, поэтому и ответ, опубликованный ниже не подошел, показывайте весь зависимый код.

Answer (score 1):

Не самое оптимальное решение, но основываясь только на том коде, чтов вы показали, можно предложить следующее

```
private async Task foo()
{
    LoadingSplash.DisplayLoadingWindow();
    await Task.Run(()=>LoadDatabaseData());
    LoadingSplash.CloseLoadingWindow();
}
```

Но также стоит пояснить, что желательно сами операции по работе с БД или файловой ситемой держать асинхронными. То есть решение, что я предложил, сработает, но оно не самое лучшее.

Comment: Ругается на попытку обратиться к элементу управления "не из того потока, в котором он был создан".

Comment: то есть вот тут `LoadDatabaseData` вы не только грузите данные, но и с UI работаете? Так не надо делать. Я вам показал, как выполнить загрузку асинхронно, примените этот подход там, где вам он подойдет.

Comment: Рекомендуете вынести логику чтения данных из базы в отдельный метод? Необходимо попробовать. Возникает ещё один вопрос. После загрузки данных, их нужно где-то показать. Например, в том же DataGridView. Заполнение данных в DataGridView ведь наверняка тоже трудоёмкая задача. Здесь так же возможно использовать Ваш подход?

Comment: 1) Да, все, что касается получения данных, но не касается UI, можно вынести в отдельные потоки. Пример, что я показал выше, выносит выполнение в потоки из пула потоков. 2) Это отдельная тема. Спросите себя - а надо ли вам рендерить огромное количество данных? Почему нельзя показать только те данные, что полезны для юзера?Почему нельзя показывать данные постранично?Все ли данные, что вы собрались показывать, реально юзеру нужны? Но даже если вы собираетесь показать большое количество данных, многие контролы поддерживают виртуализацию-то есть рендеринг только данных, что в текущий момент видно.

Comment: также, повторюсь ещё раз, чтение из БД лушче сделать асинхронным. Это позволит не тратить поток на чтение и сделает вашу программу менее требовательной к ресурсам.

Comment: Вы поставили хорошие вопросы. Необходимо подумать. Благодарю за содействие.